# How to give Data trigger property for custom usercontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created the custom usercontrol for datagrid as CustomDatagrid.  And i am using that custom datagrid in another usercontrol as DatagridUserControl. I added Textblock inside the CustomDatagrid in DatagridUserControl. I gave x:Name for Textblock in DatagridUserControl.

```
                                <GridControl:CustomDatagrid  Grid.Row="2" Height="260" Width="640" x:Name="GridTask"  BorderThickness="0" FontSize="24"  Foreground="White"   SelectionChanged="slmGridTask_SelectionChanged"
                                         ColumnWidth="*"  CanUserResizeColumns="False" Background="Transparent">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                      <DataGrid.Columns>
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <Grid Margin="-50,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <WrapPanel Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-50,0,0,0">
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
                                         TextAlignment="Justify" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-20,0,0,0"  />                                                                
                                                        </WrapPanel>
                                                        <Grid Margin="-60,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" >                                                                                                                             
                                                            <TextBlock  x:Name="TxtBlkDescription" Margin="0,0,0,0"  TextWrapping="Wrap"   Text="{Binding Description}" Visibility="Collapsed" FontWeight="Regular" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Open Sans"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                                        </Grid>
                                                    </Grid>                                                       
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                                </GridControl:CustomDatagrid>
```

That textblock should display only if datagridrow is selected. So I added DataTrigger property for Textblock.

```
                                                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" Value="True">                                                           
                                                            <Setter TargetName="TxtBlkDescription" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

But I received the following error

Cannot set Name attribute value 'TxtBlkDescription' on element 'TextBlock'. 'TextBlock' is under the scope of element 'SLMDatagrid', which already had a name registered when it was defined in another scope.

How to overcome this error?

Or is there is any other way to display the Textblock only if Datagridrow is selected?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You'll need to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). When I strip out all the unnecessary stuff from the above it works fine, which suggests there's something else in the code responsible for this behavior which you haven't included.

Comment: I think you have used same name of TextBlock 'TxtBlkDescription' somewhere else for naming other control. Try searching for the same using Find window if don't remember where have you used.