# How to solve the error in naming the control inside custom DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created the custom data grid in seperate usercontrol called CustomDatagrid. I am using that custom data grid in another usercontrol named CustomUserControl. And I added textblock in the CustomUserControl. While I am trying to run the code, it is showing following error

> Cannot set Name attribute value 'txtblock' on element 'TextBlock'.
> 'TextBlock' is under the scope of element 'SLMDatagrid', which already had a name registered when it was defined in another scope.

My first question is why this error is coming and how to solve this error?

And my requirement is I created one column for radio button. If I checked that RadioButton in particular row, one parameter(e.g Name) in itemsource should display in another column of the same row. If i changed the RadioButton selection, that parameter should not display for previous one but should display for current selected one.

I tried to add a DataTrigger for a Textblock. But it is not working.

Updated the code as below

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>            
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanToVisibilityConverter"></BooleanToVisibilityConverter>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
       
<GridControl:CustomDatagrid  x:Name="slmGridTask" Style="{StaticResource DatagridStyle}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RadioButton  Checked="RadioButton_Checked" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                    <TextBlock  x:Name="txtblock" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Text="Name">
                                                </TextBlock>                    
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>        
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</GridControl:CustomDatagrid>
```

In c# code

```
    private bool isChecked=false;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set
        {
            isChecked = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs ("IsChecked"));
        }
    }
    private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsChecked = true;
    }
```

Is there is any way to achieve this?

Comment: The first error occurs when you trying to define same element id on 2 controls and the second control fail to set the name property because it must be unique

Comment: Simply remove `x:Name="txtblock"` from your TextBlock. Your requirement for your second question is unclear. Do you mean each row should have a radio button and a textblock, and when the radio button is checked on a row, that row's textblock should be visible?

Comment: why have you posted this again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62159327/how-to-give-data-trigger-property-for-custom-usercontrol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool? isChecked = true;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool? IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set
        {
            isChecked = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked"));
        }
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Then your xaml would bind to your view model properties

```
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">

        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanToVisibilityConverter"></BooleanToVisibilityConverter>
        </DataGrid.Resources>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <RadioButton GroupName="group" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Which gives something like:

[image]

Comment: I have added the INotifyProperty and BooleanToVisibilityConverter. Though it is not working.It is hitting the Notify Property everytime when checking and unchecking the Radio button.  I think BooleanToVisibilityConverter is not working. How to do that?

Comment: Have you created a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` static resource anywhere? Update your question with your new xaml

Comment: i have edited my code. Will you please tell me why it is not working?